# Given a function, prove that it's injective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Given a function $f: \mathbf{N}_0 \to \mathbf{N}_0$, defined
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+3 & \text{if } x \in \mathbf{N}_{\text{even}} \\
x-1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbf{N}_{\text{odd}}
\end{cases}
$$

I have to prove that the function is injective.

My attempt:

Suppose that $f(a) = f(b), \forall a,b \in N_{even}$

$a+3=b+3 \implies a = b$

Suppose that $f(a) = f(b), \forall a,b \in N_{odd}$

$a-1=b-1 \implies a = b$

Since $a,b$ are arbitrary, $f$ is injective.

Comment: What is $N_{even},N_{odd},N_p,N_d,?$

Comment: Set of natural even numbers and set of natural odd numbers.

Comment: You only prove $f(a)=f(b) \implies a =b$ when both $a,b$ are even or both or odd. You either need to prove it for the other case or show that case doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but your attempt is incomplete.

What you have to prove is that, if $f(a)=f(b)$, then $a=b$.

There are four cases:

1. $a$ and $b$ even
2. $a$ even and $b$ odd
3. $a$ odd and $b$ even
4. $a$ and $b$ odd

In case 1, we have $a+3=b+3$, hence $a=b$.

In case 4, we have $a-1=b-1$, hence $a=b$.

You’re missing the other two cases, which actually are the same, so I’ll only deal with 2. In this case, $a-1=b+3$, therefore
$$
a=b+4
$$
which is a contradiction.

The fact that cases 2 and 3 can’t happen doesn’t allow you to skip them without justification.

Comment: Why is it a contradiction?

Comment: @MarcoCarta $b$ is even, so $b+4$ is even as well. But $a$ is assumed to be odd.

Answer (score 3):

Proving that $f$ is injective means to prove that$$(\forall a,b\in\mathbb{N}_0):f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b.$$So, take $a,b\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and assume that $f(a)=f(b)$. Note that $f$ maps odd numbers into even numbers and vice-versa. So, since $f(a)=f(b)$, $a$ and $b$ are both odd or both even. If $a$ and $b$ are even, then$$f(a)=f(b)\iff a+3=b+3\iff a=b.$$If $a$ and $b$  are odd, then$$f(a)=f(b)\iff a-1=b-1\iff a=b.$$

Comment: So my attempt is right?

Comment: @Marco Carta There are two problems: you only check that all the even (/odd) numbers have different images, NOT that even and odd numbers can't have the same image (easy). And, you use the symbol $\forall$ in the wrong way. Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: @MarcoCarta No, because you wrote “Suppose that $f(a) = f(b), \forall a,b \in N_{even}$”. That's **not** what *injective* means. And at no point you explaind why is it that, if $f(a)=f(b)$, then $a$ and $b$ have the same parity.

Comment: Do I have to write all of your answer to prove the injectivity or only the 3 equations?

Comment: @MarcoCarta If a student of mine provided an answer which consisted only of the three expressions which you describe as “equations”, I would see it as very far from a complete answer.